# Stopping scanf from scanning after a given amount of inputs [c]

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, eof

I am trying to scan (15 or less) numbers into the variable/array  `array[15]`, I want it to stop scanning when either the input is `EOF` "CTR+Z", or when there has been 15 values entered, I tried using `( i < 15 )` as shown below, but it doesn't really seem to get the job done, any help would be appreciated

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

     int main(){
     int array[15], i = 0;
     printf( "Please enter a sequence A: " );
     while( (scanf( "%d", &array[i]) != EOF) || ( i < 15 ) ){
          printf( "%d ", array[i] );
          i++;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The condition is wrong. Your loop will continue to read as long as `scanf` doesn't return `EOF`, no matter the value of `i`. Do some experimenting with the two logical operator `||` and `&&`.

Comment: *Also* the condition you have for `scanf` will not handle invalid input well, when `scanf` returns `0`.

Comment: Lastly, consider the order of the conditions you have, and how [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) works. If `i` reaches the limit you will still attempt to read input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `&&` instead of `||`

`while( (scanf( "%d", &array[i]) != EOF) && ( i < 15 ) ){`

The condition to again accept is when there is no `EOF` **and** the accepted inputs are less than 15

Comment: in that case, it will "continue" scanning, but only the first 15 values will be saved, I am trying to get to stop from scanning after the 15th input

[link] (https://gyazo.com/3534f0f3b0dfcb8fd8db086415bce97a)

Comment: @AhmadKhateeb "false AND true" is false, while "true OR false" is true. Please read up on how logic works.

Comment: @AhmadKhateeb No it won't continue scanning as it will exit the while loop. Please run the code and check

Comment: The `i < 15` test is too late.

Answer (score 2):

Code has 3 problems

```
while( (scanf( "%d", &array[i]) != EOF) || ( i < 15 ) ){  // problem code
```

1. Need to use `&&` rather than `||` to insure both tests pass.  [@Sniper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532015/2410359)
2. Array index test is too late.  Do first.  [@Some programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531979/stopping-scanf-from-scanning-after-a-given-amount-of-inputs-c/47535473#comment82020484_47531979)
3. `scanf( "%d", &array[i])` returns 0, 1, or `EOF`.  Only on 1, does code set `array[i]`. [@Some programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531979/stopping-scanf-from-scanning-after-a-given-amount-of-inputs-c/47535473#comment82020415_47531979)

Fixed

```
while(i < 15  && scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1) {  // fixed code
```

Comment: what should I do if I"m scanning strings into an array of max size 10 ,but I want to stop at any earlier arbitrary position ...??

Comment: @NehalSamee `while(i < 10  && scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1) {` all ready does that for you.  `while( (scanf( "%d", &array[i]) != EOF) && ( i < 10 ) ){` does not.